# Mean value from part of normal distribution

Tags: normal-distribution

I have a problem to solve. Lets say that there is normal distribution with mean value 5000 and deviation 1000.
I have to know lets say what is a mean o 25 percent biggest numbers. How to calculate that? I know that result should be between 6500 and 8000, and closer to first value, but how to calculate it correct? Is there a function for this?

---

Maybe I did not write it clear. What I need to calculate is for example average weight of 50% or 25% of biggest part of population. I know that I can split population into for example 10 buckets and then I will now that from 0-1000 there is 0% from 1000 to 2000 there is 2% ad so on. From 5000 to 6000 will be 30% and from 9000 to infinity almost 0%. Then if I will revert this calculation I can estimate what is an average of biggest 50% numbers, by average from each bucket starting from biggest ones, get average of it. But with having only 10 buckets the estimation is not precise enough. I could split it to thousands of buckets to get more accurate number, but do think this is best way. There must be some formula to calculate this in easier way.

Comment: "mean o 25 percent biggest numbers"? Do you mean a value $y$ so that $P[X>y]=.25$ where $X$ is your rv? If so, convert to the standard normal and then do a "reverse table lookup" in a CDF table for the standard normal rv.

Comment: @David Mitra: The wording is hard to decipher. But it might be conditional expectation, given that $X$ is above the $75$-th percentile.

Comment: I'm pretty sure André Nicolas' interpretation is right.