# Mean of a portion of a normal distribution?

Tags: statistics, probability-distributions, normal-distribution

How do I calculate the mean of a portion of a normal distribution.  In other words, say I have a normal distribution of the heights of adult males.  The mean is 70" and the standard deviation is 4".  What is the average height of males above the 95th percentile?  What is the average height of all males below the 95th percentile?  How do I calculate this?

Someone asked a similar question here which was never answered clearly:

[Mean value from part of normal distribution](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/106444/mean-value-from-part-of-normal-distribution)

This question has a practical application for my work where I am running a power plant at 10.3 MW mean operating point with a standard deviation of 0.2 MW.  I would like to know the average power when I am above 10 MW.  Or the mean of all points above 10 MW.

Comment: See [truncated normal distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Truncated_normal_distribution)

Answer (score 2):

Suppose $X$ is normal with mean $\mu$ and standard deviation $\sigma$. Then $Z=\frac{X-\mu}{\sigma}$ is normal with mean $0$ and standard deviation $1$, and $X=\sigma Z + \mu$. Then

$$E[X \mid X \in [a,b]]=E[\sigma Z + \mu \mid X \in [a,b]] \\
= \mu + \sigma E[Z \mid X \in [a,b]] \\
= \mu + \sigma E \left [Z \left | Z \in \left [ \frac{a-\mu}{\sigma},\frac{b-\mu}{\sigma} \right ] \right. \right ] \\
= \mu + \sigma \frac{E \left [ Z 1_{[\frac{a-\mu}{\sigma},\frac{b-\mu}{\sigma}]}\right ]}{P \left ( Z \in \left [\frac{a-\mu}{\sigma},\frac{b-\mu}{\sigma} \right ] \right )} \\
= \mu + \sigma \frac{\int_{\frac{a-\mu}{\sigma}}^{\frac{b-\mu}{\sigma}} x e^{-\frac{x^2}{2}} dx}{\int_{\frac{a-\mu}{\sigma}}^{\frac{b-\mu}{\sigma}} e^{-\frac{x^2}{2}} dx}.$$

The numerator can be calculated in terms of elementary functions using the FTC, since $-x e^{-x^2/2}$ is the derivative of $e^{-x^2/2}$.

The denominator is an integral of the standard normal density, which cannot be calculated in terms of elementary functions, but can be easily evaluated using software, using functions generally called either "erf" (for "error function") or "normcdf".

$$= \mu + \sigma \frac{ e^{-\frac{\left ( a-\mu\right ) ^2}{2\sigma^2}} - e^{-\frac{\left ( b-\mu\right ) ^2}{2\sigma^2}} }{ \sqrt{\frac{\pi}{2}}\left ( \text{erf}\left ( \frac{b-\mu}{\sqrt{2}\sigma}\right ) - \text{erf}\left ( \frac{a-\mu}{\sqrt{2}\sigma}\right ) \right ) }$$

Comment: Sorry about [that](https://math.stackexchange.com/revisions/1546141/5). I realize it's an indicator now! @Ian

Answer (score 0):

I think you just need to take the values/points (which are above 10MW), sum them up and divide the sum by their count. That's all, no? Whether the distribution is normal or not, that's not relevant here, I think.

Comment: That only applies if you have discrete points, otherwise use integral

Answer (score 0):

The "mean" of a continuous probability distribution, P(x), is, by definition, the integral of xP(x).  To restrict a normal distribution, $y= Ae^{\frac{(x- \mu)^2}{\sigma^2}}$, between x= a and x= b, with a< b, we have to divide by the probability x **is** between a and b, the integral of P(x) between a and b.  Here, mean is $\frac{\int_a^b xe^{\frac{(x- \mu)^2}{\sigma^2}}dx}{\int_a^b e^\frac{(x- \mu)^2}{\sigma^2}dx}$

Answer (score 0):

Suppose for simplicity that you have a standard normal $X$ with pdf $f$. One of the main properties of $f$ is that it satisfies $f'=-xf$ which implies $\int_a^b xf\,dx=-\int_a^b df=f(a)-f(b)$.

It follows that $$E(X|X\in[a,b])=\frac {f(a)-f(b)}{\Phi(b)-\Phi(a)}$$

Set $b=\infty$ ($\Phi(\infty)=1, f(\infty)=0$) if you want a one-sided bound.

Comment: What if there is a sign change prohibiting the substitution? (Your formula actually still works out, but you haven't explained why.) Also, you should have $-\int_{f(a)}^{f(b)} df$.

Comment: @Ian What sign change and how can it prohibit a substitution?

Comment: You may only make a substitution if the substitution function is monotonic over the entire interval in question. This is part of the hypotheses of the change of variables theorem.

Comment: @Ian $\int_a^b f'dx=\int_a^b df=f(b)-f(a)$ is a FTC. No change of variables., no need for monotonicity.

Comment: Ah, I see, carry on. You still have the error in the limits, though.

Comment: @Ian you are mistaken. The limits are correct since it's $df(x)$

Comment: You didn't write $df(x)$, you wrote $df$, so your integration variable is just $f$, and the limits apply to $f$. Writing $df$ when you mean $df(x)$ is abuse of notation. Reusing the variable $f$ in the first place is also an abuse of notation, albeit a less confusing one.

Comment: Perhaps what I mean here would be more obvious if you imagine taking $\int_a^b df$ out of context. Would it mean $f(b)-f(a)$ then? I claim that it would mean $b-a$.

Comment: @ You see variables where there are none. I'm not reusing the variable $f$. I'm simply writing a Riemann-Stieltjes integral with respect to $f$. It's very common to write $df$ instead of $df(x)$ in such a case since $f$ is clearly a *function*, not a *variable*. Saw your comment. I somewhat see your point, but it's so common for $f$ to denote a function and not a variable that I see little need to emphasize it.

Comment: Except in a context where that sort of usage is very common, for instance when writing $dF$ where $F$ is a CDF in a probability context, I think this usage should either be discouraged or explicitly labeled at least once (by something like "where the latter integral is a Stieltjes integral with respect to $x$"). It is quite prone to confusion. Part of the problem is that the common notation surrounding integration by substitution blurs the distinction between function and variable quite frequently anyway.

Comment: For instance you already saw that I genuinely thought you were computing $\int xf dx$ through the *substitution* $xf=-f'$.

Comment: @Ian If I were to believe you, writing $f'=xf$ is also abuse of notation since it should be $f'(x)=xf(x)$ as $f$ without $(x)$ is just a "variable" and not a function. I'm used to probability context and even Mathworld gives it as an [example](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/StieltjesIntegral.html). When one does integration by parts one regularly writes $u\,dv=d(uv)-v\,du$ while dropping the underlying variable without any confusion. I don't know why you saw a substitution where there isn't one. What possible substitution could there be?

Comment: You're right, $f'=xf$ is also an abuse of notation. But not all abuses of notation are created equal; some are more or less prone to causing confusion. For instance, $f'=xf$ only makes sense if $x$ is understood as an argument of $f'$ and $f$, whereas $\int_a^b df$ could mean $b-a$ or $f(b)-f(a)$ depending on whether you're abusing notation.

Comment: Anyway, returning to the problem, there is a substitution that can be done, it's just a somewhat trivial one: if $u(x)=f(x)$ then $u'(x)=-xf(x)$, so $\int_a^b xf(x) dx = -\int_{f(a)}^{f(b)} du$ by substitution. Of course proceeding this way you have to be careful about monotonicity, which your argument avoids.

Comment: @Ian I see your point now though $f$ is never, *ever* used as a variable (esp. in calculus context) - only as a function - so there should be no confusion as to the meaning of $df$. Added: otherwise $f'=xf$ could be understood with $f$ a variable and $x$ a function (to mean $1=fx(f)$) but nobody means/understands it this way.